# Wordpress slider with 4 posts per slide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a project which has a slider of posts(posts of a specific category). No problems. But the slider should show 4 posts at once (something like a post grid on each slide). Any idea how I can solve this? This is the code I'm using to print the posts in the slider. This is my second WordPress project and I don't have much knowledge in PHP. Thanks for your attention and sorry for my bad english!

```
<ul class="slides">
<?php
query_posts(array('category_name' => 'marcar-na-timeline'));
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<li>
<ul>
<li class="item">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="post-item-container<?php echo $opener_class; ?>">
<div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?></div>
<div class="item-content">
<div class="date">
<span class="day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></span>
<span class="monthandyear"><?php the_time('M y'); ?></span>
</div>
<div class="item-description">
<?php echo get_uf('description'); ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<?php
   endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
```

(I'm using flexslider)

Answer (score 0):

use WP_Query class:

```
$slider_post= new WP_Query('category_name='your catagory name'& showposts=4');
if($slider_post -> have_post()) : while($slider_post->have_post()){
      $slider_post->the_post();
      // echo html slider item 
}
```

I hope it useful for u.